# GitLab ships a wrong C# code encoding. Ways to fix this

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, gitlab

GitLab ships a wrong C# code encoding. Maybe someone might know a reason for this and a way to fix this?

I am working on a project for something like 3 months. All that time I worked from the office, so I did not have to deploy the project locally at my home computer, only at the computer on work. There on work I somehow managed to deploy a project successfully, but here at home while deploying and setting everything up I come across errors in the project.

All due to that piece of code:

```
public static object ParseReferred(this JObject item, JsonSerializer serializer, RetypeEnum retype)
{
   if (item == null)
   {
      return null;
   }

   if (retype == RetypeEnum.)
   {
      return serializer.Deserialize(item.CreateReader(), typeof(TypeRegNumber));
   }

   return serializer.Deserialize(item.CreateReader(), typeof(TypeTaskNumber));
}
```

Here is how I see that piece in GitLab:

[image]

Here is the GitLab raw view:
[image]

Raw code:

```
public static object ParseReferred(this JObject item, JsonSerializer serializer, RetypeEnum retype)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (retype == RetypeEnum.�)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(item.CreateReader(), typeof(TypeRegNumber));
        }

        return serializer.Deserialize(item.CreateReader(), typeof(TypeTaskNumber));
    }
```

I suspect that the only one who could have helped me with the issue was my team lead. So, I asked him what I could do about it. He suggested the following: clearing NuGet cache, restoring NuGets, cleaning the solution, and then rebuilding the solution. I followed the steps, but with no success. I feel myself very stupid, I must have missed something.

Is it true that the only way to fix the issue is to communicate with someone who has known the codebase for sometime? Or are there other possible ways to research the issue? I am really stuck, I do not know what I can try to research the issue.

When I hover over the symbol here is what I see:

[image]

> 'RetypeEnum' does not contain a definition for 'ä'

When I open the **RetypeEnum** definition (by Ctrl+click on the **RetypeEnum**) here is what I see:
[image]

```
#region Assembly foo, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// foo.dll
#endregion

using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace foo
{
    [GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
    public enum RetypeEnum
    {
        д = 0,
        з = 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check out code files line endings.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. After your answer I now try to find a solution by somehow utilizing the [`Advanced Save Options`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/encodings-and-line-breaks?view=vs-2019) command. I tried the different encodings and the different line endings in the command and still it did not help. I won`t accept your answer just yet in the hope of a better one. Thank you once more.